# What is the connection string for a SQL Server 2012 default instance?

Tags: sql-server, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I have recently installed Windows 8 and VS 2012, now I want to connect to the SQL Server 2012 default instance, but I can't figure out what the connection string is to it.

I have tried:

```
.\sqlexpress
.\sqlexpress,1433
```

and the same connections with `pcname` instead of `.`

Comment: Did you have installed Sql Server Management Studio? Use it to search for your instance

Comment: i didn't install management studio, i thought that the default sql server express should be installed, am i wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the examples that can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752.aspx#localdb ?Also, are you trying to use SQL Express or LocalDB?

Comment: also if not connecting via localhost, check your firewall and net library (tcpip in addition to named pipes) and if remote connections have been allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has solved after installation Sql Server 2012 express and Management studio. It seems that with VS 2012 installation there were no sql server available.

Answer (score 3):

First are you using SSMS ? Or you are trying to connect using VS 2012 ? Second are you connecting to default instance of Express edition or non-express edition ? (if you are using Express edition please modify your question header and question itself to reflect that) Express edition have default name **SQLEXPRESS** and non-express edition has default name **MSSQLServer**

If you need to know instance of SQL Server that you are trying to connect, it can be found by looking at SQL Server Configuration Manager (SSCM). Also make sure that SQL Server service is running.

If instance name is correct, then I would look at SQL Native Client Configuration -> Client Protocol in SSCM and check if TCP/IP is enabled or not.

If that is enabled then I would check if firewall is blocking the connection or not.

As a side note, if you are using default port then you don't have to explicitly define port when trying to make connection.

Answer (score 1):

if you use localDB:(i think you used this)

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

if you use sql server express

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
```

or if you have a database in an .mdf file in the App_Data folder.

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```